EC2 instance is frequently unreachable
I host my website in an EC2 t2.micro instance with 1 CPU and 1 GB RAM. Currently, the instance is configured to run:

Apache 2 server
Spring boot Java application
MySQL server

After adding the MySQL server, the EC2 instance is frequently unreachable, making my website globally down. Here is the error message from the system log:
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS ip-172-31-10-80 ttyS0

ip-172-31-10-80 login: [   85.979209] ================================================================================
[   86.007944] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /build/linux-aws-6.5-jxebbQ/linux-aws-6.5-6.5.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:824:4
[   86.027139] index 243 is out of range for type 'xen_netif_tx_sring_entry [1]'
[   86.034546] ================================================================================
[   89.858011] cloud-init[778]: Cloud-init v. 24.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.5 running 'modules:config' at Fri, 30 Aug 2024 13:53:35 +0000. Up 88.17 seconds.
[  100.787495] cloud-init[801]: Cloud-init v. 24.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.5 running 'modules:final' at Fri, 30 Aug 2024 13:53:47 +0000. Up 100.27 seconds.
[  101.504162] cloud-init[801]: Cloud-init v. 24.1.3-0ubuntu1~22.04.5 finished at Fri, 30 Aug 2024 13:53:49 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 101.43 seconds

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue or troubleshoot it?
Here is the screenshot of the EC2 instance for reference:
image

There's nothing in the log that can help us diagnose that problem. You're probably running out of RAM. Configure MySQL to use much less RAM. My t3a.nano EC2 server running LAMP including MySQL 8+ has been running for years with no problems - with occasional upgrades and reboots.
